# Why counter variable is unreachable even when code worked initially?

Tags: java, for-loop, counter, unreachable-code

I was doing fun coding. This method calculates the grade for a range. The problem arose after I added this line after for loop,       `average= average/i;` 
I know how to fix it, but I cannot figure out why it arrived? Can someone help me? 
I got an error that says this line is unreachable.

```
 char calculate(){
   int i, average=0;
    for( i=0; ; i++) {
        average=average + testScores[i];           
    }
    average= average/i;
    char grade='A';
    if(average>=90 && average<=100)
        grade='O';
    else if(average>=80 && average<90)
        grade='A';
    else if(average>=70 && average<80)
        grade='B';
    else if(average>=55 && average<70)
        grade='C';
    else if(average>=40 && average<55)
        grade='D';
    else if(average<40)
        grade='T';
    return grade;
}
```

Comment: Your for loop has no end condition. It'll run until it crashes with an index error.

Comment: ...so, everything that comes afterwards is unreachable, since for all eternity the computer will be stuck in your `for` loop, never reaching the code that lies beyond!

Comment: Yes, I got it... I got puzzled before because earlier I was getting a grade, however without the average division. Why so then, it could have also have resulted in the error.